# Normal distribution,expectations in F distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Let $_1, ... , _{10}$ be independent and identically distributed normal random variables with mean $0$ and variance $2$.
Then
$ ( X_1^2/(X_1^2 +X_2^2 + \dots +_{10}^2))$ is equal to ...

My solution:
Numerator is chi square with 1 df and denominator is chi square with 10 df
Division of both follow F distribution now mean of F distribution is (10/(10-2))

But the answer in book is 0.1

I don’t know what is wrong in this

Comment: You don't have independence here --- the denominator is always going to be greater than the numerator, so it is not the $F$ distribution.  Instead use symmetry and permute the $X_i$s.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_1, \dots X_{10}$ are i.i.d. then the random variables
$$
Y_i = \frac{X_i^2}{X_1^2 + \dots + X_{10}^2} 
$$
have the same distribution (in particular, $\mathbb{E} Y_i$'s are the same). Moreover, since $$\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i = 1 \implies \mathbb{E} Y_i = \frac 1 {10},$$
as the answer in the book.